# Does ישב בשער־המלך imply some sort of royal position

Tags: sources-mekorot, megillat-esther, mordechai

In Esther 2:19 Mordechai is described as  ישב בשער־המלך sitting at the gate of the king. I recall learning that this implied that Mordechai held some sort of royal/official government position. I would like to know if this is true and if so what the source is for this idea.

Comment: It is definitely true that in Eretz Yisrael, the people who "sat at the gate" were the elders of the city. (See e.g. Eshet Chayil). I'm not sure about Persia, but it's plausible.

Comment: @DanielKagan wow, you have no idea how helpful that comment was. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [*Ralbag* and *Malbim*](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Esther.2.19) say so. Not all commentaries agree with this, though.

Comment: Could you please summarize in English?